# How do i chain these two jquery statements into one?

Tags: jquery

Ok, I want to chain these statements into one, but i don't know how it works yet..

I have lots of input in my html file, and then if i click a link, it will just check that link and make other input check boxes uncheck.. Here's my current code for that:

```
$('.category').click(function() {
   $('input[name=category]').attr('checked', false);
   $(this).parent().find('input').attr('checked', true);
}
```

I think this might be slow because the second statement will go to its parent and then find the input then checked it.. It might be possible to combine these into one and make it faster?

Comment: For mutually exclusive options, surely it would be better to use radio buttons instead? With regards to your current statements, they look fine. How slow is it? Seconds? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: i need it to be a checkbox because sometimes 2 options can be selected

Comment: Well without knowing the DOM context it's a bit hard to give you the best solution. Where is .category placed? In a div just before the inputs? In a complex architecture ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that call to `.parent().find()` on your chain makes me think that you're actually looking for a sibling? You may get better mileage by using the `.siblings()` function.

With that in mind, you may want to phrase your code like this:

```
$('.category').click(function(){
    $('[name="category"]').attr('checked',true);
    $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').attr('checked',true);
});
```

It's difficult to construct a proper chain for your particular DOM without first seeing the code, but the code above should be OK. Doesn't look heavy at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can add extra filtering into your .find() to only look for checkboxes

```
$(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Make finds just once...

```
var $category = $('input[name=category]');
var $inputs = $('your_parent_selector');
$('.category').click(function() {
   $category.attr('checked', false);
   $inputs.attr('checked', true);
}
```

Comment: What would `this` refer to in `$(this).parent().find('input');` ? It has to be inside the click event. The category selector can be done outside of the click event though like you've done so it is not run more than once.

Comment: @InfernalBadger: you are right, I copied it quickly, what I meant, and understood, is parent selector is only one-for-all. If not that must return into click fuction. Sorry